# combination lock logic - reactive cocoa

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I'm completely new to Reactive Cocoa. After spending some time going through the documentation and some tutorials, I think I must be missing a trick whilst trying to do something relatively simple (I hope!).

I'm trying to write the logic for a 4 digit combination lock as an exercise.

the user uses a scrollwheel to input and can only input number 2 when number 1 is correct, nunber 3 when number 2 has been selected etc. Basically, I need to watch the input stream of numbers, check against the 'correct' number and, when they are equal, advance the system to check against the second digit of the pass combination.

I can see how to make a RACSignal from the user input, but I am not sure about what pattern to use to check against the 'correct' digit in order to progress the sequence RACSequence with...filter:?...combineLatest:?

I'm just trying to get my head around this, so code examples are appreciated, but a general conceptual pointer in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Looks like I skimmed over the middle of your question. Have updated my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it: Assuming you have a signal of NSNumbers representing the current value of each wheel on the lock and a `successIndicator` indicating whether or not the combination is correct:

```
NSArray *correctCombination = @[@1, @2, @3, @4)];
RACSignal *currentCombination = [RACSignal combineLatest:@[digit1, digit2, digit3, digit4];

RACSignal *(^hasCorrectValue)(NSUInteger idx) ^(NSUInteger idx){
    return [currentCombination map:^(RACTuple *currentCombination) {
        return [currentCombination[idx] isEqual:correctCombination[idx]];
    }];
};

__block RACSignal *(^hasUnlockedStage)(NSUInteger idx) = ^(NSUInteger idx){
    if (idx == 0) return hasCorrectValue(idx);
    else return [hasCorrectValue(idx) and:hasUnlockedStage(idx - 1)];
};

[hasUnlockedStage(0) setKeypath:@keypath(wheel2, enabled) onObject:wheel2];
[hasUnlockedStage(1) setKeypath:@keypath(wheel3, enabled) onObject:wheel3];
[hasUnlockedStage(2) setKeypath:@keypath(wheel4, enabled) onObject:wheel4];
[hasUnlockedStage(3) setKeypath:@keypath(successIndicator, active) onObject:successIndicator];

hasUnlockedStage = nil; // nil out recursive block
```

The middle part, where the logic happens, is very similar to the non-reactive:

```
BOOL(^hasCorrectValue)(NSUInteger idx) ^(NSUInteger idx){
   return [[views[idx] currentValue] isEqual:[correctCombination[idx] currentValue]];
};

__block BOOL(^hasUnlockedStage)(NSUInteger idx) = ^(NSUInteger idx){
    if (idx == 0) return hasCorrectValue(idx);
    else return hasCorrectValue(idx) && hasUnlockedStage(idx - 1);
};
```

Once all the inputs are represented as signals, we can proceed roughly as we would in standard Objective-C, substituting the RAC operations (which operate on streams of values) for normal operations (which operate on values).

Each operation represents a step transforming a stream of values into another stream of values. Each step results in a new signal which represents a further step converting our initial stream of values into the stream of values we want.

Relatedly, the last operation has no output signal, and is only place where we cause any side-effects. It's good practice to separate the logic that transforms and combines values and the logic that performs side-effects. This way, we can add additional observers to the locked signal, or refactor the code affecting locked without worrying about unintended consequences.

A nice next exercise would be to handle changes to the correct combination, or the number of wheels on the lock.

Comment: Hi Chris, apologies for not getting back to you sooner, just wanted to be able to get my head around your answer. It has helped a lot and I now have a much better understanding of whats going on, though I'm yet to take up your 'next exercise' challenge! maybe soon....hopefully this example Q&A will be useful for others too.